# On any select option display only last inserted record

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have a little problem. I have a simple select field and get options from the database when the user clicks on any option I get an input box with the name of the last inserted record from the database, and I need to display the input box with the name of what the user selected not the last record. Code is bellow:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<label>Odaberite dimenziju produkta</label>
    <select class="select2" name="size_id[]" multiple="multiple" id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
            <?php
                $get_sizes = "select * from sizes";
                $sizes = mysqli_query($con,$get_sizes);
                while($row_size = mysqli_fetch_array($sizes)){
                $size_id = $row_size['id_size'];
                $size_name = $row_size['productSize'];
                $i++;
                echo "<option value=".$size_name.">".$size_name."</option>";
            } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
<div id="textboxcont" style="display: inline-flex; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFunc() {
        document.getElementById('textboxcont').innerHTML = '';
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
        var selectedValues = Array.from(document.getElementById('selectBox').selectedOptions).map(el=>el.value);
        //alert(selectedValues)
        for( var i = 0; selectedValues.length > i; ++i ) {
            var i1 = document.createElement("input");
            i1.setAttribute("type", "text");
            i1.setAttribute("name", "<?php echo $size_name; ?>");
            i1.setAttribute("id", "<?php echo $size_name; ?>");
            i1.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter price for <?php echo $size_name; ?>");
            i1.setAttribute("class", "form-control txtt");
            // you may want to change this
            // add the file and text to the div
            document.getElementById('textboxcont').appendChild(i1);
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

I need when the user clicks on one of four available selected options to display selected inputs with different names. Now when users select any 1 or 2 or 3 available options they display only the last records from the database. Any help why?

Comment: If you don't require Server information, do it all on the Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having problem here..

```
   for( var i = 0; selectedValues.length > i; ++i ) {
        var i1 = document.createElement("input");
        i1.setAttribute("type", "text");
        i1.setAttribute("name", "<?php echo $size_name; ?>");
        i1.setAttribute("id", "<?php echo $size_name; ?>");
        i1.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter price for <?php echo $size_name; ?>");
        i1.setAttribute("class", "form-control txtt");
        // you may want to change this
        // add the file and text to the div
        document.getElementById('textboxcont').appendChild(i1);
    }
```

Your $size_name var contains last value of the query data array that you looped already while adding options to the select.

You should not use that to set attribute while creating input.

You should use the values that you have collected in selectedValues.
You can either itarate through it or use array index like  selectedValues[ i ] to set input attribute like below.

```
function changeFunc() {
    document.getElementById('textboxcont').innerHTML = '';
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValues = Array.from(document.getElementById('selectBox').selectedOptions).map(el=>el.value);
    //alert(selectedValues[0]);
    for( var i = 0; selectedValues.length > i; ++i ) {
        var i1 = document.createElement("input");
        i1.setAttribute("type", "text");
        i1.setAttribute("name", selectedValues[i]);
        i1.setAttribute("id", selectedValues[i]);
        i1.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter price for " + selectedValues[i] );
        i1.setAttribute("class", "form-control txtt");
        // you may want to change this
        // add the file and text to the div
        document.getElementById('textboxcont').appendChild(i1);
    }
}
```